# How to change data in page init Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is a snippet of a larger app that plots user-selected data.  On `Page1` (not shown), the user identifies the text file to plot.  Then, a function `transferToPlotPage()` saves the desired text file to an application-wide variable `app_data` and calls the next page, `PlotPage`.  `PlotPage` generates a plot based on the `x1`,`y1`,`x2`,`y2` generated from the values in the data files.

Note -  `plotData()` works if I pass it data arrays like `[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]`.  But these arrays have nothing to do with the user-selected data.  These are just hard-coded.

I intend to plot the text file data, not the hard-coded constants.  However, I realize the `PlotPage __init__` runs before I have an opportunity to let the program know what data files to use.

I have tried to call `plotData()` from `transferToPlotPage` but a blank plot is produced.  No data shows up.  I tried calling `plotData()` with the given arrays `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` from `PlotPage __init__` and also observed a blank plot.

I have verified that data exists in the arrays.

**Question:** How can I instruct the program so that the arrays plot their data on the figure on `PlotPage`?

```
def transferToPlotPage(self,controller,filename1,filename2):
        controller.app_data["filename1"].set(filename1)  # accessible from all classes
        controller.app_data["filename2"].set(filename2)  # accessible from all classes
        ...
        [extract the file data and save to arrays x1, x2, y1, y2 ]
        [ -->> Want to call plotData here <<-- ]
        ...
        controller.show_frame(PlotPage)  # Serve up the data plot

def plotData(self, controller, x1, y1,x2,y2):
        f = Figure(figsize=(7.9,3.4),dpi=100)

        # Setup figure to hold subplots
        f = Figure(figsize=(7.9,3.4), dpi=100)
        # Setup subplots
        subplot1=f.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        subplot1.plot(x1,y1, "-o")
        subplot1.set_title("Plot 1")


        subplot2=f.add_subplot(2,1,2)
        subplot2.plot(x2,y2, "-o")
        subplot2.set_title("Plot 2")

        # Show Plots
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

class PlotPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        # Window title
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        plotData(self, controller,x1,y1,x2,y2)

# Load desired page frame (elsewhere in app, but here for reference)
def show_frame(self, container):
    frame = self.frames[container]
    frame.tkraise()
```